# How to log in ArgoCD using SSO with Google email

Tags: single-sign-on, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am trying to make it possible for us to long in ArgoCD using google accounts.
Has anyone done it, and could it give me the confog and if possible some other tips arround it. Do we need rbac as weel, create groups for the users and assign policiies?
would appreciate it

I have tried this config

### Argo Configs

```
configs:
  cm:
    # -- Create the argocd-cm configmap for [declarative setup]
    create: true
    # -- Argo CD's externally facing base URL (optional). Required when configuring SSO
    url: https://company.com/api/dex/callback

    # Dex configuration
    
    dex.config: |
      connectors:
      - config:
          clientID: "${clientID}"
          clientSecret: "${clientSecret}"
          orgs:
          - name: https://accounts.google.com
        type: oidc
        id: google
        name: Google
```

Comment: You don't need RBAC to be able to log in using SSO.

Comment: Have you checked https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/#sso and https://dexidp.io/docs/connectors/google/?

Comment: You seem to have used `type: oidc` but you could use `type: google`.

Comment: @GaëlJ I havent implemented rbac yet, I am trying to authenticate from google for now

Comment: @GaëlJ used type : google and got this error

Failed to query provider "https://company.com/api/dex": Get "https://argocd-dex-server:5556/api/dex/.well-known/openid-configuration": EOF

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
dex.config: |
  connectors:
  - type: oidc
    id: google
    name: Google
    config:
      issuer: https://accounts.google.com
      clientID: $argocd-iap-oauth-client:client_id
      clientSecret: $argocd-iap-oauth-client:client_secret
```